# Categorical Foundations text

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation, foundations, topos-theory

I've heard that someone's thought up a way of using category theory, involving something called topoi, as a foundation for mathematics. If this is true then are there any texts which explain such a categorical approach to foundations? Preferably one which is self-contained, as while I'm sure I could, with time, teach myself the category theory required...I'd rather have it bundled up in a package for me.

Comment: To start, see http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Foundations book using category theory for student embarking on PhD in mathematical biology?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751906).

Comment: I looked at that, but there was only a single recommendation that looked like it might actually be suitable

Comment: The [original paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC300477/pdf/pnas00186-0196.pdf) of Lawvere is actually readable with a small categorical background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best book for your purposes would be McLarty, [Elementary Categories, Elementary Toposes.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198514735)